# What is $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}$ equal to if we have $y_1=\frac{x^2_1}{x_2},\:y_2=log\left(x_1\right)$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

We got:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}=\frac{\partial y_1\:}{\partial \:x_1}\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y_1}+\frac{\partial \:y_2}{\partial \:x_1}\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y_2}$$

But isn't this wrong? Because it would mean that:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}=\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x_1}+\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x_1}=2\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x_1}$$

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}$? Because $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}$ operates in functions like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f(x_1,x_2) $

Comment: Let's say that f(x1, x2)=1 here. What we wanted to do was to write d/dx1 (as an operator, that's how it's called?) differently with the help of dy1 and dy2, but what I see we end up getting something wrong

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}$ is an operator that works the same way as the derivative in one variable but for functions of several variables. For example if $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^3$ then $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}f(x_1,x_2)=2x_1+x_2$ ,  $x_2$ is considered a constant when you compute the derivative in order to $x_1$. Note now that if $f(x_1,x_2)=1$ then $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}f(x_1,x_2)=0$ because it does not depend on $x_1$.

Writing $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}f(x_1,x_2)$ where $f(x_1,x_2)=1$ differently with the help of $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}y_1(x_1,x_2)$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}y_2(x_1,x_2)$:

$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}y_1(x_1,x_2)=2\frac{x_1}{x_2}  \text{ and } \frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}y_2(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{x_1}$
$$\text{Therefore } 0=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}f(x_1,x_2)=0\times\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}y_1(x_1,x_2)+0\times\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}y_2(x_1,x_2)$$

Now imagine that $x_1=x_1(t) $ and $x_2=x_2(t)$ then

$\frac{d }{dt}y_1(x_1,x_2)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}y_1(x_1,x_2)\frac{d}{dt}x_1(t)+\frac{\partial }{\partial x_2}y_1(x_1,x_2)\frac{d}{dt}x_2(t)$